Length of generic intersection in local ring
Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a regular local ring and let $I\subset R$ be an ideal of coheight 1. Let $a \in \mathfrak{m}\setminus \mathfrak{m}^2$.
If $a$ that is not a zero divisor of $R/I$ we have that $R/(I+\langle a\rangle)$ has finite length over R.
Can we say that for a "generic" element $a$, this length is constant? More formally, can we say that there exists an ideal $J \subset R$ such that the length of $R/(I+\langle a\rangle)$ is independent of $a$, assuming that $a\notin J$?

You would need to allow several different possibilities for $J$.  Consider the case that $I$ is the principal ideal $\langle st\rangle$ in the power series ring $k[[s,t]]$.  You need to exclude both $\langle s,t^2\rangle$ and $\langle s^2,t \rangle$.

@JasonStarr Right. So what about if we allow more than one ideal, but still finitely many of them?
